# Cannot publish reports to Web, no access to create embed code

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

I am trying to use the pre-built embed code in COVID-19 tracking US sample to create a customised report, but can't publish on the web. Need some advise/help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since January 2020 [Publish to web](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-publish-to-web) by default is disabled. You need to get a permission from the admin of your tenant to be able to use it.

In `Tenant settings` they can change the option `Choose how embed code work`:

[image]

From there, your admin can allow you to generate new embed codes. If you don't have admin rights, you can't do anything else except asking for permission.

See: [Heads up: The Publish to web default is changing and it affects who can create public embed codes](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/heads-up-the-publish-to-web-default-is-changing-and-it-affects-who-can-create-public-embed-codes/)

Comment: Thanks, I also had the same suspicion. Let me try and get hold of the admin